# R rgdal::readOGR issue with file path refering to linux home directory

Tags: r, rgdal

This isn't a huge deal, but does anyone know why:

```
readOGR('~/documents/zipcodes', 'zipcodes')
```

Returns: "Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file"

When this:

```
setwd('~/documents/zipcodes')
readOGR('.', 'zipcodes')
```

Works perfectly?

Comment: yep. it doesn't do path expansion. You can do `readOGR(path.expand('~/documents/zipcodes'), 'zipcodes')` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use `tools::file_path_as_absolute()` like this:

```
library(tools)
readOGR(file_path_as_absolute('~/documents/zipcodes'), 'zipcodes')
```

or

`path.expand()` as hrbrmstr mentioned in his comment:

```
readOGR(path.expand('~/documents/zipcodes'), 'zipcodes')
```

Another, more inconvenient way would be to use `base::dirname()` in combination with `paste0()`:

```
readOGR(paste0(dirname('~/documents/zipcodes'), 'zipcodes'), 'zipcodes')
```